# databinding with RecyclerView where each item CheckBox

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have RecyclerView ,where each item represents, CheckBox and EditText
when clicks on CheckBox the text of EditText should strike through,
I have ObservableBoolean which is article.complete 
I used it in `app:checkBoxChangeListener="@{article.complete}"
 app:itemComplete="@{article.complete}"`

it works unless I scroll RecyclerView, then clicking on CheckBox another item’s text is strike through

```
@BindingAdapter("itemComplete")
public static void bindItemComplete(EditText itemInput, boolean complete){ 
itemInput.setPaintFlags(complete ?
 (itemInput.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) : 0);
}
```

Article.java

```
public class Article{
    public final ObservableBoolean complete = new ObservableBoolean();
}
```

xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="se.ica.handla.articles.ArticleListViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="article"
        type="se.ica.handla.models.articles.Article" />

</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:itemComplete="@{article.complete}"
/>
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checked="@={article.complete}" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: So.. in `bindCheckBox` you want to set thearticles attribute `complete`, am I right? Maybe you can achieve this with [`Two-way-Databinding`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/111/data-binding-library/6634/built-in-two-way-data-binding#t=201705030857408356564)? `Databinding` works fine for so many people - this may be an error on your side. ;)

Comment: complete is ObservableBoolean on of the ways to achieve two way binding ,I use complete in 
app:checkBoxChangeListener="@{article.complete}" for CheckBox
and app:itemComplete="@{article.complete}" in EditText ,
and it works the problem appears during scrolling

Comment: You get errors while scrolling, because you set your `complete` to the `view` - and not to the `article` (`view.setTag()...`). And because the views in a `RecyclerView` get *recycled*, the values get messed up when you scroll. The easiest way I see is to use `Two-Way databinding`. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @Amylinn I have updated my question and post my solution it works, but I didn't get the way  you are mentioning using view.setTag(), please let me know.

Comment: I just quoted your code to make it clearer - sorry if that confused you. I'm glad it works now. I'll add it as an answer, maybe I can get things more clear for you. Also, please don't edit your question code with a solution, it hides the problem for other users and will confuse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in my comments, I recommend you to use **Two-way-Databinding**.

You can completely delete this `BindingAdapter`:

```
 @BindingAdapter(value = {"checkBoxChangeListener", "article"}, requireAll = false)
 public static void bindCheckBox(CheckBox view, final ObservableBoolean checked, Article article) {     
      if (view.getTag(R.id.binded) == null) {     
          //Here you are setting the attributes to your *view* and 
          //decouple it from your article. It does not reference it, 
          //the properties (isChecked) isnow on the view.               
          //So when your view gets recycled when you scroll, 
          //it still has the property you set the last time - 
          //and not from your current article, which is displayed now in the view. 

          view.setTag(R.id.binded, true);
          view.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> checked.set(isChecked));}
      }
 }
```

As you already found out, your xml should look like this now, using Two-Way Databinding:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:itemComplete="@{article.complete}"
/>

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checked="@={article.complete}" //@={} for Two-Way Databinding
/>
```

Comment: Yes , I see ,but for this example android:checked="@={article.complete}" @={} works as android:checked is standard attribute

but when I want to try it for custom attribute app:focus I could not use @={} 
 app:focus="@{article.focus}"
and I have this method and I’m facing the same issues when scrolling

  @BindingAdapter(“focus”)
    public static void bindFocus(EditText itemInput, ObservableBoolean focus) {
        if (focus.get()) {
            itemInput.requestFocus();
        } else {
            itemInput.clearFocus();
        }
    }

Comment: You need an `InverseBindingAdapter` for custom Two-Way Databinding. You can check [George Mounts article](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-2-way-your-way-ccac20f6313) about this topic.